# Null and Empty record with query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have question regarding NULL and '' (Empty) data.
Below is the query

```
with tempCTS
as(
select null as [blank] ) 
select * from tempCTS t
```

Output is NULL

Another Query with Empty Check

```
with tempCTS
as(
select null as [blank] ) 
select * from tempCTS t where  t.blank <> ''
```

Ouput is nothing

My question is why the null records are not fetching once the black checked is placed

PS:- I need null and data records but not the one having empty string

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you need to use isnull or is null, depending what DBMS you use to check for nulls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Null value*** is not an ordinary string (icluding empty string), number etc. *Null* means "*unknown*", "*doesn't matter*" etc. That's why

```
  null <> ''
```

is not either *true* or *false* - it's again *null* (what else it could be? Just imagine comparison like *if I don't know what <> ''*. The result is *I don't know what*, there's no data to put it true or false). So

```
 select ... 
  where null <> ''
```

doesn't return any record. To test for null use ***is null***:

```
  with 
    tempCTS as (
       select null as [blank]) 
  select * 
    from tempCTS t 
   where t.blank is null -- <- Is null
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)

Comment: So in case we need Null records then we need to specify "Is null" always? @Dmitry Bychenko

Comment: @Amit Soni: yes, according SQL 92 standard either `is null` or `is not null`